# Table cells breaking across pages loose their top and bottom obrders

Tags: html, css, asp.net

When a table cell is broken across two pages, it looses its top and bottom borders.

I have a table which has cells with high (hundreds of pixels) heights. When this table is printed, cells which are broken across pages won't have bottom borders (on starting page) and top borders (on next page). I have seen this behavior before, but need some css/html tricks to prevent this, so the output is more acceptable by my users.

This is what I get with current code:

[image]

And this is what I want:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It won't work. that is the default printing behavior. print function will just print the page how much each page contain. it will cut off once page end and start from the new page with cut off part to print in next page.